# I need something like "how to calculate equilibrium price for complete idiots"

Tags: calculus, economics

My grandfather rises, sells and resells livestock and I want to help him by calculating when and for what price to (re)sell or buy livestock. As far as I understand(although I have a hunch that I need something more), I need to calculate so-called "equilibrium price". I know only school level of mathematics(I know how to plot functions, find a derivative, find a primitive function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simple way to do this would be to observe the peaks of the functions of "supply" and "demand". Now, it can be done pretty easily, but under the condition that you have some data to use. And if you have the data, this means that you are already behind the market.

Usually the challenge is in predicting those prices, to make some decisions.

Knowledge of programming would greatly help as you could plot and analyse the data in real time.

I'd suggest to first collect some data on how high does the livestock sell, when is the best time to sell it (usually this is when you use "equilibrium prices"), and when is it the cheapest to buy.

Then you could possibly either use math tools , which would involve either solving systems of equations or finding derivatives, or you could use computer soft to do it for you.

At the end, you should take a look at what you obtained, and use statistical models (the most rudimentary would be the best fit line / polynomial), so that they give you the tendencies of this market.  Keep in mind that they will give you the general behavior, but things like cataclysms, conflicts and other events are really hard to predict, but they for sure influence the market prices.

Good luck!